# Níveis de acesso de login

Tags: php, mysql

Como eu consigo fazer com que só mostre para o usuário que estiver com `$cargo == 'Administrador'`?

Vi muitos sendo usados com número, mas quero deixar registrado com nome Administrador ou Visitante e assim no menu, conseguir que seja mostrado só para o usuário que estiver com cargo Administrador.

Seria algo assim?

```
<?php
if($cargo == "Administrador"){
?>
        <li>
          <a href="?p=inicio">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Inicio</span>
          </a>
        </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: E como você está atribuindo um valor a variavel `$cargo` para comparar com `Administrador`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou lhe explicar rápido e objetivo em texto certo?

Ao validar o login, você provavelmente trará dentre os resultados da consulta, o nome de usuário e o campo que estiver utilizando para atribuir o nível de acesso, confere?

Guarde-os em uma uma [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), de forma que possa fazer sempre que necessário essa verificação e conceder ou negar acesso.

Seu exemplo está correto, só falta implementar algo no sentido que lhe sugeri.